# Update RTE component to use Block Quotes in AEM

Tags: aem, rte

I'm currently using Rich Text Editor (RTE) in my AEM 6.2 project. I would like to configure RTE to use blockquote tag. How can achieve this?

```
<blockquote>
```

Component code:

```
<paraformat jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*">
    <formats jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <p  jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Paragraph" tag="p"/>
        <h1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Heading 1" tag="h1"/>
        <h2 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Heading 2" tag="h2"/>
        <h3 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Heading 3" tag="h3"/>
        <h4 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Heading 4" tag="h4"/>
        <h5 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Heading 5" tag="h5"/>
        <blockquote jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Block Quote" tag="blockquote"/>
    </formats>
</paraformat>
```

Reference:

[RTE in JCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e0m1.png)

[Dialog View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihYLr.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *configure*? Do you want RTE to show `blockquote` as an option or do you want it to allow `blockquote` to be rendered? These are two different problems, hence asking.

Comment: What I meant was to allow RTE to use the `blockquote`.

Comment: See my answer below. I have covered both issues. Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new block element by following the instructions at official documents:

[Adding custom paragraph formats to RTE](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#Paragraph%20Formats)

Basically, you overlay the RTE and extend the paraformat plugin by introducing the new elements. Summary steps are:

1. Overlay your RTE
2. Create cq:EditConfig/inplaceEditing/paraformat/format node under your RTE control.
3. Create a node for your style, name it `blockquote` and give it the following properties -> `Description: Block Quote` & `Tag: blockquote`
4. Make sure you add all other default formats like p, H1, H2 etc.

That's it. You should see your new paragraph style available in the paragraph styles dropdown.

> This is a summary as all the pictures will make this post too long but a detailed post can be found at: http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/configure-rte-plugin-in-touch-ui/

Optionally, you will need to check if blockquote element is allowed by inspecting your `/libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml` file. The file is self explanatory with lots of comments but in general you should check under `<tag-rules>` to ensure that your tag is supported. OOTB AEM 6.2 allows `blockquote` element but some upgrades might have lost it.

Comment: Awesome!! It worked!! Thank you!!

The last step regarding `config.xml` is very nice to know.

Comment: Glad it worked. I was scratching my head after your update on what could be wrong! Accept answer if you wish. This might help others. The config.xml is a pain especially for legacy configs carried over from upgrades.